# check_balance() function not giving out correct values / values are not stored

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm writing a bank-teller project.

I'm creating a function called check_balance() to check the two types of balances and two other functions one named make_deposit() and the other make_withdrawal().

The thing is my check_balance() function is not giving out the supposedly-updated balances...seems like the make_deposit function did not store the values at all. I'm copy-pasting all codes below, please let me know why it's not working properly. Thanks !!

Code below:

```
checking_balance - 0
savings_balance = 0

def check_balance(account_type, checking_balance, savings_balance):
    if account_type == "savings":
        balance = savings_balance
    elif account_type == "checking":
        balance = checking_balance
    else:
        return "Unsuccessful, please enter \"checking\" or \"savings\""
    balance_statement = "Your " + account_type + " balance is "+ str(balance)
    return balance_statement

def make_deposit(account_type, amount, checking_balance, savings_balance):
    deposit_status = ""
    if amount > 0:
        if account_type == "savings":
            savings_balance += amount
            deposit_status = "successful"
        elif account_type == "checking":
            checking_balance += amount
            deposit_status = "successful"
        else:
            deposit_status = "Unsuccessful, please enter \"checking\" or \"savings\""
    else:
        deposit_status = "unsuccessful, please enter an amount greater than 0"
    deposit_statement = "Deposit of " + str(amount) + " to your " + account_type + " account was " + deposit_status + " ."
    print(deposit_statement)
    return checking_balance, savings_balance

print(make_deposit("savings", 10, checking_balance, savings_balance)) ---> this gives a savings_balance of 10. 

print(check_balance("savings", checking_balance, savings_balance)) ---> Now this gives 0 instead of 10.
```

Comment: When you say it's not working properly, it's helpful if you explain what you want it to do.

Comment: Check out python passing by reference and value. When you pass `savings_balance` into `make_deposit`, it won't actually edit the global variable.

Comment: Both `checking_balance` and `savings_balance` are zero and never changed. So the code gives expected results for the provided values.

Comment: I see where the issue is now, but how do I make the balances updated? Now I deleted the two global variables and put them inside the check_balance() function, but the values won't update. Sorry I'm a bit slow.

Comment: I want the check_balance() function to actually store the values after I put 10 in the savings account.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a class for this project and putting your functions in there. You can modify the code below to better fit your needs. This is a really good article showing how to use a class for a banking project (ironically enough) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-create-bankaccount-class-with-deposit-withdraw-function/

```
class Bank_Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Chekingsbalance=0
        self.Savingsbalance=0
        print("Hello!!! Welcome to the Python bank")

    def Deposit(self, AccountType):
        if AccountType == "checking":
            amount=float(input("Enter amount to be Deposited: "))
            self.Chekingsbalance += amount
            print("\n Amount Deposited into checking:",amount)
        if AccountType == "savings":
            amount=float(input("Enter amount to be Deposited: "))
            self.Savingsbalance += amount
            print("\n Amount Deposited into savings:",amount)

    def Balance(self, AccountType):
        if AccountType == "savings":
            print("\n Net Available Balance=",self.Savingsbalance)
        if AccountType == "checking":
            print("\n Net Available Balance=",self.Chekingsbalance)


# Driver code

# creating an object of class
s = Bank_Account()

StopBanking = False

while StopBanking ==False:
    tasks = (input('What would you like to do? enter [deposit], [check balance], or [quit]'))
    # Calling functions with that class object
    if tasks == 'deposit':
        account = (input('deposit into which account? enter [checking] [savings]'))
        if account == 'checking':
            s.Deposit(account)
        if account == 'savings':
            s.Deposit(account)

    if tasks == 'check balance':
        accountbalance = (input('check balance of which account? enter [checking] [savings]'))
        if accountbalance == 'checking':
            s.Balance(accountbalance)
        if accountbalance == 'savings':
            s.Balance(accountbalance)
    if tasks == 'quit':
        print("thanks for banking!")
        StopBanking =True
```